# Date format changing passing date from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When passing a date from a MVC view, to a GET action in the controller the date value changes from `01/03/2018 00:00:00` to: `03/01/2018 00:00:00` I have attempted to format it using `@Model.CalendarOptions.DefaultDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` but it behaves the same.  Any ideas?

`<a class="modal-link btn btn-default pull-right" id="calendar-booking-button" data-target="modal-container" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="CreateModal" asp-controller="Bookings" asp-route-bookingStartDate="@Model.CalendarOptions.DefaultDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" asp-route-staffid="@staff.StaffId">`                                                      `

I saw a post advising to add localization in the startup however that has not helped.

```
      services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-GB");
            options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
        });
```

Comment: A date only has a format when you look at it in some way. For the purposes of your business logic do you care what it looks like in the debugger? The DateTime variable will have the same value.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am using this value to set another value that is used in my modal view model, but then in my modal view the input that uses this value is set to 03/01/2018 in the datepicker instead of 01/03/2018

Comment: You can Try `DateFormat.TryParseExact`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Round-trip" format to pass the date (`DateTime.ToString("o")`). This is an unambiguous [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
<a asp-route-bookingStartDate="@Model.CalendarOptions.DefaultDate.ToString("o")">
```

[How to: Round-trip Date and Time Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-round-trip-date-and-time-values)

[The Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)

Comment: Always glad to help :)